# Python: Find strings in two file and print all the line

Tags: python, pandas

i need to find an occurrency from a file in an other.

My files are like this:

FILE1: CLUSTER_NAME

FILE2: TIMESTAMP, CLUSTER_NAME, LOG

What i want is to check if CLUSTERS that are in the first file, are even in the second file and print all the line.

For example:

FILE1:

- clusterA,
- clusterB,
- clusterC,

FILE2:

- 2019, clusterB, log
- 2020, clusterC, log
- 2017, clusterZ, log

Output should be like this

```
Input: clusterB, clusterZ
output: 2017, clusterZ, log
        2019, clusterB, log
```

```
import pandas as pd

#ARRAY
my_value = []
cluster_value = []

#READ THE FILES
my_data_file = pd.read_csv('my_data.txt', sep=',')
log_file = pd.read_csv('log.txt', sep=',')

#TAKE THE COLUMN WITH THE CLUSTERS
for row in my_data_file[my_data_file.columns[1]]:
    my_value.append(row)

for row in log_file[log_file.columns[0]]:
    cluster_value.append(row)

#Restult
print("_______________")
print(list(set(my_value) & set(cluster_value)))
print("_______________")
```

It works, but i need to print all the log. I don't kwon how to link the result of my operation to print what i need.

Comment: `FILE2[FILE2.CLUSTER_NAME.isin(FILE1.CLUSTER_NAME)]` ?

Comment: I’d like to think there is a python module for such a process that negates the need for Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions

- Don't need Pandas for this simple file read.

**Code**

```
import re

def search(key_file, search_file):
    with open(key_file) as kfile:
      keys = '|'.join(line.rstrip().split(',')[0] for line in kfile.readlines())
    # regex for cluster names
    regex = re.compile(keys)

    with open(search_file) as search_data:
      for line in search_data:
        if regex.search(line):
          print(line.rstrip())

search('mydata.txt', 'log.txt')
```

**Input**

'mydata.txt' (note ',' doesn't matter i.e. ignored)

```
clusterB,
clusterZ
```

'log.txt'

```
2019, clusterB, log
2020, clusterC, log
2017, clusterZ, log
```

*Output*

```
2019, clusterB, log
2017, clusterZ, log
```

Comment: I think that there is somenthing to fix.
My ouput is all the file. Like if the search is not working.

Comment: @cescov91--here's [an online link](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/MediumorchidSmallPhases) to my running code.  You can run by hitting the run button at the top (green with arrow).  Output will appear on screen on right.  Let me know what the difference is.  Thanks.

Comment: Online works, on my machine with pycharm not. I tried on another laptop and works. Probably some issues with version. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @cescov91--glad it worked. Since the solution only uses basic Python I guess the pycharm version is 'crippled' on your machine.